# jquery - defining options dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dry, jquery-dialog

So just to describe what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to make an easy way to create modal messages. Trying to reduce code repetition (I don't want to create dialogs for everything). So hopefully I'll be able to just define the title and content and buttons for a modal and then call a function (doModal()).

For some reason the code below does no pass the buttons correctly (no buttons are shown). If I simply substitute `modal.buttons` with this:

```
{
                thisone: function(){
                    alert('you clicked this one');
                }
            }
```

then it would work. But then I can't have an easy way of defining the buttons, which is against what I'm trying to do.

Here's the current code:

```
var modal = $('<div id="modal"><p></p></div>');
function doModal()
{
    var modal = $('<div id="modal"><p></p></div>');
    modal.text(modal.content);
    modal.attr('title', modal.title);
    modal.dialog('destroy');
    modal.dialog({
        modal:true,
        resizable:false,
        draggable:false,
        buttons: modal.buttons
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    modal.title = 'Are you sure?';
    modal.content = 'Are you sure? Deleting a product cannot be undone.';
    modal.buttons = {
            thisone: function(){
                alert('you clicked this one');
            }
        };
    doModal();
});
```

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357506/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-better-way-to-create-content-of-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define modal 2 times, global and inside doModal()

Inside the function you call on document.ready() you assign the buttons to the modal defined in global scope. But inside doModal() there also exists the local defined variable modal, which to you doesn't assign the buttons.

I would define modal inside the ready()-function and pass it as argument to doModal() :

```
function doModal(modal)
{ 
    modal.text(modal.content);
    modal.attr('title', modal.title);
    modal.dialog('destroy');
    modal.dialog({
        modal:true,
        resizable:false,
        draggable:false,
        buttons: modal.buttons
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var modal = $('<div id="modal"><p></p></div>');
    modal.title = 'Are you sure?';
    modal.content = 'Are you sure? Deleting a product cannot be undone.';
    modal.buttons = {
            thisone: function(){
                alert('you clicked this one');
            }
        };
    doModal(modal);
});
```

or pass only the dynamic options to doModal():

```
function doModal(options)
{ 
    var modal = $('<div id="modal"><p></p></div>');
    modal.text(options.content);
    modal.attr('title', options.title);
    modal.dialog('destroy');
    modal.dialog({
        modal:true,
        resizable:false,
        draggable:false,
        buttons: options.buttons
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    doModal(
            {
              title   :'Are you sure?',
              content :'Are you sure? Deleting a product cannot be undone.',
              buttons : {
                          thisone: function()
                                   {
                                      alert('you clicked this one');
                                   }
                        }
             }
           );
});
```

Comment: except I don't want to have to define modal as '$(...)' every time I want to create a modal. I'm trying to reduce repetition as much as possible. What if doModal could be a function of modal or something and then I would just define it once and such?... Close though, it's working at least.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help. I created a 'growl' jQuery library that displayed a modal dialog. It doesn't have the button, but I think you can extend it. Here is a link to the library.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/making-the-web-growl-using-jquery/

Hopefully this gives you some ideas and is helpful.

Bob